# Scrape data from dynamic Highcharts visualisation

Tags: web-scraping, highcharts

I have tried to use the code snippets using `soup` in previous questions on stackoverflow, but failed.

How can I scrape all the data from this (https://ieademoviz.azurewebsites.net/ETP2020-ownership) dynamic Highcharts visualisation?

What is particularly tricky is scraping it across all years, i.e. through all the slider "dimensions".

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jackk, You can get data by global variable: `Highcharts`, for example: `Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions.series[x].data`

Answer (score 0):

The data is from this JS file: https://ieademoviz.azurewebsites.net/static/js/main.0e14eb2b.chunk.js
You can extract from it somehow.